CSS linear gradient displayed multiple times
I implemented a linear-gradient effect in the CSS on my HTML website. However, upon viewing it, I noticed that the gradient was being displayed multiple times.
For context, my website is powered by nginx, and I use Express.js along with EJS for server-side rendering.
Any insights or suggestions on how to resolve this issue would be greatly appreciated.


* {
    margin: 0;
    font-family: Roboto,Arial,sans-serif;
    font-weight: bold;
    
}

@font-face {
    font-family: 'Mokoto Glitsch 2';
    src: url('../fonts/mokoto-mokoto-regular-glitch-mark-2-400.ttf') format('truetype');
    
}

body {
    background: linear-gradient( #D077E8, #01536C);
    background-size: cover;
    user-select: none;
    overflow: hidden;
}

header {
    position: relative; 
    width: 100%;
    height: 70px;
    color: white;
    background-color: #010F27;
}

.server-tool-text {
    font-family: 'Mokoto Glitsch 2', Arial, sans-serif;  
    line-height: normal;
    margin-top: 7px;
}

.logo {
    float: left;
    font-size: 25px;
    margin-left: 30px;
    height: 70px;
    display: flex;
    align-items: center;
}

.profile-picture {
    width: 50px; 
    height: 50px; 
    border-radius: 50%; 
    object-fit: cover; 
    margin-right: 10px;
}
.profile-name {
    margin-right: 10px;
}

.user-menu {
    float: right;
    margin-right: 10px;
    text-decoration: none;
    height: 70px;
    display: flex;
    align-items: center;
}

.user-menu a {
    text-decoration: none;
    margin-right: 20px;
    color: white;
}

.menu {
    float: left;
    margin-left: 40px;
    text-decoration: none;
    height: 70px;
    display: flex;
    align-items: center;
}

.user-menu a {
    text-decoration: none;
    margin-right: 20px;
    color: white;
}

.menu-button {
    font-size: 15px;
    margin-left: 15px;
    color: white;
    background-color: #010F27;
    width: 150px;
    height: 40px;
    border-radius: 5px;
    border: None;
    transition: background-color 0.3s;
}

.menu-button:hover {
    cursor: pointer;
    background-color: rgb(8, 9, 22);
    transition: background-color 0.3s;
}

.log-in {
    font-size: 14px;
    color: white;
    background-color: #010F27;
    width: 80px;
    height: 40px;
    border-radius: 5px;
    border: None;
    transition: background-color 0.3s;
}

.log-in:hover {
    cursor: pointer;
    background-color: rgb(8, 9, 22);
    transition: background-color 0.3s;
}

.log-out {
    font-size: 14px;
    color: white;
    background-color: #ff0000;
    width: 80px;
    height: 40px;
    border-radius: 5px;
    border: None;
    transition: background-color 0.3s;
}

.log-out:hover {
    cursor: pointer;
    background-color: #690101;
    transition: background-color 0.3s;
}

.invite-button {
    font-size: 20px;
    margin: 0;
    position: absolute;
    top: 75%;
    left: 40%;
    transform: translate(-50%, -50%);
    color: white;
    background-color: #010F27;
    outline: 2px solid #00367c;
    width: 200px;
    height: 50px;
    border-radius: 5px;
    border: None;
    transition: background-color 0.3s;
}

.invite-button:hover {
    cursor: pointer;
    background-color: rgb(8, 9, 22);
    outline: 2px solid #003f91;
    box-shadow: 0 0 10px 2px rgba(0, 162, 255, 0.7);
    transition: background-color 0.3s;
    transition: outline 0.3s;
    transition: box-shadow 0.3s;
}

.dashboard-button {
    font-size: 20px;
    margin: 0;
    position: absolute;
    top: 75%;
    left: 60%;
    transform: translate(-50%, -50%);
    color: white;
    background-color: #010F27;
    outline: 2px solid #00367c;
    width: 200px;
    height: 50px;
    border-radius: 5px;
    border: None;
    transition: background-color 0.3s;
}

.dashboard-button:hover {
    cursor: pointer;
    background-color: rgb(8, 9, 22);
    outline: 2px solid #003f91;
    box-shadow: 0 0 10px 2px rgba(0, 162, 255, 0.7);
    transition: background-color 0.3s;
    transition: outline 0.3s;
    transition: box-shadow 0.3s;
}


.titel {
    position: absolute;
    top: 40%;
    left: 50%;
    width: 800px;
    transform: translate(-50%, -50%);
    padding: 10px;
    color: white; 
    
}
.titel-subtitel {
    position: absolute;
    top: 50%; 
    left: 50%; 
    transform: translate(-50%, 50%); 
    width: 500px;
    padding: 10px;
    color: white;
    text-align: center; 
}
<!DOCTYPE html>

<html>

<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <title>Server Tool</title> 
    <base href="https://servertool.xyz/">
    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="assets/css/style.css">
    <link rel="icon" type="image/ico" href="assets/favicon.ico">
</head>

<body>
    <header>
        <span class="logo">
            <img src="assets/img/servertool-logo.png" style="width: 65px; height: 65px; border-radius: 20%;" />
            &nbsp;
            <span style="color: white; font-weight:900;" class="server-tool-text">Server Tool</span>

        </span>
        <span class="menu">
            <a href='https://servertool.xyz/support'><button class='menu-button'>Support Server</button></a>
            <a href='https://servertool.xyz/docs'><button class='menu-button'>Documentation</button></a>
        </span>
        <span class="user-menu">
            <a href='https://servertool.xyz/login'><button class='log-in'>Login</button></a>
        </span>
    </header>

    <h1 style="font-weight:900; font-size: 24px; white-space: pre-line; " class="titel">
        <span style="color: white; font-weight:800; font-size: 30px;">Server Tool App and Website are in Development</span>
        <span style="color: white; font-weight:900;  font-size: 15px;" class="titel-subtitel">You can finde more information on our Support Server</span>
    </h1>
    <a><button onclick="inviteServerTool()" class="invite-button">Invite Server Tool</button></a>
    <a><button onclick="gotodashboard()" class="dashboard-button">Dashboard</button></a>

<script>
     function inviteServerTool() {
        var url = "https://discord.com/oauth2/authorize?client_id=1236000476143685762&permissions=8&scope=bot+applications.commands";
        var width = 450;
        var height = 750;
        var left = 0;
        var top = 0;
        window.open(url, "_blank", "width=" + width + ", height=" + height + ", left=" + left + ", top=" + top);
        }

        function gotodashboard() {
            window.location.href = `https://servertool.xyz/dashboard`;
        }
</script>

</body>

</html>




html {min-height: 100%} and you should avoid using position:absolute to create your website

body hasn’t got the height you think it has because of the floats and absolutes. I’d suggest recoding all that positioning stuff. Maybe flex and/or grid would help.

Add "background-attachment" property for your body tag css
body {
    background: linear-gradient( #D077E8, #01536C);
    background-size: cover;
    user-select: none;
    overflow: hidden;
    background-attachment: fixed;
}

The background-attachment CSS property sets whether a background image's position is fixed within the viewport, or scrolls with its containing block
For reference https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/background-attachment

This doesn’t work well on Safari/iOS because of background-attachment. Avoid it and instead sort out the fact that all those absolutes and floats mean body hasn’t got the height you think it has (so what is actually seen is html’s background)
